# How get ResourceUrl from Katharsis

Tags: katharsis

When I try to rewrite Katharsis self link,  I need add resource url as prefix.

e.g: "self": "http://localhost/table-name/A" 
Where I can get http://localhost/table-name.

I found ResourceRegistry provider this method. but I am not able to get ResourceRegistry  instance。
Is any good way to get ResourceUrl ?

```
ResourceRegistry
 public String getResourceUrl(Class<?> clazz)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `localhost` part will be picked up from the host header. The prefix can be set in your application properties file. I think it's literally called `api.prefix`. If you want to override the local host part programmatically you can implement a bean of type

`ServiceUrlProvider` and declare it `@Primary`

Look at the spring boot example config